# Python Find x in file and add following lines until not indented

Tags: python

Python Find x in file and add following lines until not indented

I have a file like below

```
T01_JOB1
 T01_JOB1a
 T01_JOB1b
 T01_JOB1c
T01_JOB2
 T01_JOB2a
 T01_JOB2b
  T01_JOB2c
  T01_JOB2d
  T01_JOB2e
T01_JOB3
T01_JOB4
 T01_JOB4a
 T01_JOB4b
 T01_JOB4c
  T01_JOB5
   T01_JOB5a
    T01_JOB5b
```

All jobs without indentation are top level so have taken that information.

```
topboxes=[]
for line in batchjobs:
    if line.startswith(b'T0'):
        topboxes.append(line)
```

example what I am trying

topjobs = ('T01_JOB1', 'T01_JOB2', 'T01_JOB3', 'T01_JOB4')

jobgroups = {(T01_JOB1,T01_JOB1a,T01_JOB1b,T01_JOB1c),(T01_JOB2,T01_JOB2a,T01_JOB2b,T01_JOB2c,T01_JOB2d,T01_JOB2e),(T01_JOB3),(T01_JOB4,T01_JOB4a,T01_JOB4b,T01_JOB4c,T01_JOB5,T01_JOB5a,T01_JOB5b)}

(job5 is within job4 tree and that's ok)

This comes out with [b'T01_JOB1\n', b'T01_JOB2\n', b'T01_JOB3\n', b'T01_JOB4\n'] which is fine

I now want to go through the list again and this time bring all the indents underneath, stopping when I get to a line without the indent.

```
topboxesjobs={}

for line in batchjobs:
    for x in topboxes:
        if x in line:
            #print(x, 'imhere')
            topboxesjobs.append(x)
            if line.startswith(b' '):
                topboxesjobs.append(x,line)
                continue
                print(topboxesjobs)
            if line.startswith(b'T0'):
                exit()
```

But this isn't working.  Any suggestions please?

Comment: "I now want to go through the list again and this time bring all the indents underneath, stopping when I get to a line without the indent." **What does this mean**? For the given input file (by the way, [please show textual input as text, not an image](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551)), **what should the result be**, and why? Are you trying to create a data structure, or display some information? (Your life will be **much** easier if you accept that these are **completely separate ideas**, and write separate code to handle each.)

Comment: I added an image as when I was trying to add the text it was losing the indentation/formating

T01_JOB1
 T01_JOB1a
 T01_JOB1b
 T01_JOB1c
T01_JOB2
 T01_JOB2a
 T01_JOB2b
  T01_JOB2c
  T01_JOB2d
  T01_JOB2e
T01_JOB3
T01_JOB4
 T01_JOB4a
 T01_JOB4b
 T01_JOB4c
  T01_JOB5
   T01_JOB5a
    T01_JOB5b

Top list is T01_JOB1, T01_JOB2, T01_JOB3,T01_JOB4

Comment: Please [edit] the question to include the text. "when I was trying to add the text it was losing the indentation". To solve this, format the text the same way as the code block.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have interpreted your question in the following way:

Since you want to have ALL the indents, I do not see a need for an exit() in the for loop, elsewise you would always quit after job1.

So I have redesigned your code to go through the list again, picking up topjobs as keys and using these keys to create a dictionairy of subjobs.
I use [defaultdict](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.defaultdict) from the collections-module of the standard library to directly append to an empty list inside the dictionairy without needing to initialize this list first.

```py
from collections import defaultdict
from pprint import pprint

batchjobs = """T01_JOB1
 T01_JOB1a
 T01_JOB1b
 T01_JOB1c
T01_JOB2
 T01_JOB2a
 T01_JOB2b
  T01_JOB2c
  T01_JOB2d
  T01_JOB2e
T01_JOB3
T01_JOB4
 T01_JOB4a
 T01_JOB4b
 T01_JOB4c
T01_JOB5
  T01_JOB5a
   T01_JOB5b""".splitlines()  # pseudo file-content

# get topboxes
topboxes=[]
for line in batchjobs:
    if line.startswith('T0'):
        topboxes.append(line)

# get dict for sub-jobs
topboxesjobs=defaultdict(list) # directly append to an empty list
job_key = None
for line in batchjobs:
    if line in topboxes:
        job_key = line  # new topbox found, this is the current key
    if line.startswith(' ') and job_key:
        # append sub-jobs in the dict with the current key
        # use strip() to get rid of indentation whitespace
        topboxesjobs[job_key].append(line.strip())

#pretty print the defaultdict
pprint(dict(topboxesjobs))
```

which *hopefully* gives you your desired output:

```
{'T01_JOB1': ['T01_JOB1a', 'T01_JOB1b', 'T01_JOB1c'],
 'T01_JOB2': ['T01_JOB2a', 'T01_JOB2b', 'T01_JOB2c', 'T01_JOB2d', 'T01_JOB2e'],
 'T01_JOB4': ['T01_JOB4a', 'T01_JOB4b', 'T01_JOB4c'],
 'T01_JOB5': ['T01_JOB5a', 'T01_JOB5b']}
```

Comment: Thank you, this seems to work.  
T01_JOB3 doesn't appear because it doesn't have any jobs in it so I added an alert to sweep any of these up.

`for x in topboxes:
    if x not in topboxesjobs:
        print(x,"is missing")`

I will try with live data once I have a chance.  Thanks again, it looks very good.  Never used the pretty print before.

Comment: Oh, good catch, i did not even notice that job3 was missing.  Checking this in the end is a good idea!

Comment: Ran it through with the data and exactly what I wanted. Thanks again.